# cross compiler for java for ubuntu on windows

Tags: java, windows, ubuntu, cross-compiling

I am deploying a java application in windows IDE but this application will be run in Ubuntu. What cross compiler do I need to compile in windows and then deploy it in Ubuntu?

Thank you,

Comment: Java is cross-platform already. Classes compiled with Windows should work in Ubuntu .

Comment: Java works on any platform. You can compile your code on windows and run it on Ubuntu, and vice-versa.

Comment: Little anecdote: i once worked on project, developers worked on windows, automated build on linux, and final deployment was on AIX machines. No cross-compilers needed :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Java compilers are cross-platform. That's one of the most important characteristics of Java.
Java compiles to byte-code, which is the interpreted by a virtual machine. If a computer has a virtual machine it can run byte code generated in any operating system.